# MVC 4 BundleConfig not creating script references

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm adding a few jQuery script files to my app using the bundleconfig.cs class.

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.min.js",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.mousewheel.min.js",
                    "~/Scripts/jtable/jquery.jtable.js"));
```

When I run my app and check the page source, only some of the script files are referenced:

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.3.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jtable/jquery.jtable.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

Why would this be happening? I can work around the issue by manually adding the script references directly to _Layout.cshtml, but that is hardly best practice.

Comment: Are you sure the files exists, and you point to their exact relative URL? Most issues like this, is because the file cannot be found.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The **.min** part is already handled by MVC - it will automatically include **.js** files for Debug mode and **.min.js** files for Release mode.

Just download the unminified version of **jquery.mCustomScrollbar.min.js** and put it in your scripts directory, then reference it as:
**jquery.mCustomScrollbar.js**

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.js",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.mousewheel.js",
                    "~/Scripts/jtable/jquery.jtable.js"));
```

MVC will then load the appropriate script for Debug/Release

Comment: Thanks Blade. Seems you hit the nail on the head. All script refs are now being included correctly.

Comment: No problem, happened to me the first time I used bundling :)

Comment: THANK YOU!  just spent several hours chasing my tail on this.... demo's tomorrow :|

Answer (score 2):

It could be so because you didn't enable bundling.
Try to change debug attribute value on compilation to false

```
<compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.0" />
```

Or enable it manually:

```
BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
```